# How to move massive files from one drive to another quickly in Python?

Tags: python, performance, large-files, pathlib

I am moving massive files in Python on Ubuntu, roughly several hundreds of gigabytes in size, from one drive to another.  I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to transfer them than this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm

large_file = Path('/path/to/file')

new_loc = Path('/new/file/loc')

chunk_size = 4096

with large_file.open(mode='rb') as old_file, new_loc.open(mode='wb') as new_file, \
    tqdm(total=large_file.stat().st_size) as progress:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: old_file.read(chunk_size), b''):
        new_file.write(chunk)
        progress.update(len(chunk))
large_file.unlink()
```

I know there is the [`shutil.move` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move), however, my main issue with this function is there is no way to see how much of the file has transferred unlike the method above.  If anyone has experience transferring massive files in Python please let me know if the speed difference between the [`shutil.move` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) and the method proposed above is noticeable. Additionally, if there is a completely different solution, please also let me know.  Would it be worth it to use some type of C-extension or `ctypes` for this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how *shutil.move()* is implemented but I would expect it be like *mv* on Unix-like systems. *mv* will be extremely fast when the source and target files are on the same filesystem because it doesn't actually copy the file - it just moves the inode reference from one directory to another (possibly with a filename change). However, if source and target are on different filesystems then I would expect it use the most efficient mechanism available to the underlying OS for copying. Your code will always copy the file even if source and target are on the same filesystem

Comment: I very much doubt you will get even close to a disk's maximum speed with 4kB chunks, I would benchmark that but suspect you should use at least 64kB. Also, you should probably double-buffer and multithread so that while one thread is writing block N, the other is reading block N+1.

Comment: @BrutusForcus In this use case the source and target files will always been on different file systems.

Additionally, if there is any kind of error the file will not be delete as when an error is raised in Python, the program sys.exit dead in its tracks with the error traceback as output.  In fact the file will only ever be deleted if there are **no errors.**

Comment: Hey @MarkSetchel, thanks for the feedback.  I am new to this area of programming, so I have no idea what a good chunk size is.  If it helps at all this code will be transferring files (that are several hundreds of GBs in size) from one SATA SSD to another SATA SSD.  Additionally, if possible do you think you could provide an example of how to multithread this?  Thank you! ♥️

Comment: With a good chunk size, there is often no need to use multiple threads on SATA SSD (limited to about 500 Mo/s). 64 KiB seems quite good for a SSD but one can try empirically bigger ones like 256 KiB. The chunk size should not be too small due to system calls and bounded IOPS and not too big either because of additional throughput overheads in a situation where the SSD is saturated. Typically it should not be bigger than the cache size. Some platforms can cache write so they are done asynchronously very quickly in parallel to reads.

Comment: Hey @JérômeRichard thanks for the info.  Is there a way I can find out what the cache size for my drives are?  Additionally, I just was informed that my code will also need to transfer from a SATA SSD to a SATA hard drive as well. Will this affect the chunk size I should use?  Thank you! ♥️

Comment: If you know the exact name of you processor, you can go to the vendor website where it is indicated. On Windows, the name is shown on the right of the Performance>CPU tab of the task manager. You can also get the L3 cache size with the command `wmic cpu get L3CacheSize` (for the L2 you should divide the result by the number of cores on almost all x86 processors). On Linux, it is stored in the CPU Gnome system configuration manager. Alternately, it is stored in `/proc/cpuinfo`. You can also get very detailed information with the command `lstopo` (require the package `hwloc`)

Comment: Hard drives (HDD) are very slow, both in terms of IOPS and throughput. You can write relatively small chunks of data chunks in hard drives efficiently as long as they are sequential each other (because the system should bufferize it). Still it should be better to use much bigger chunks size, typically few MiB (if possible, less than the L3 cache but this does not have a big impact on HDD). The average speed of a HDD is about 100 MiB/s and 50-500 IOPS while SATA 6G SDDs often reach 500 MiB/s and 50000~120000 IOPS. Note that Nvme/M2 SSD are even much faster and SATA 3G much slower than that.

Comment: You need to balance the importance of being able to indicate progress and efficiency of the file transfer (move). Whilst *shutil.move()* doesn't give you any means of knowing anything about its progress, it is more likely to offer the best efficiency in executing the file transfer because it can take advantage to OS specific mechanisms that are not directly available to the Python programmer

Comment: 1) The sequential write speed is pretty much always slower than the sequential read speed of most disks, so the writing speed will pretty much determine the maximum speed at which you can copy files and you should be able to mask the reads behind the slower writes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Could you provide an example (in code) of what you mean by "mask the reads"? That would be really helpful

Comment: @BrutusForcus *"masking"* means *"hiding"*, you just hide the faster `read` behind the slower `write`. You can do it with two threads or with asyncIO, it is also called *"double-buffering"* or *"ping-pong"*. You make 2 or more buffers and have one thread repeatedly read from disk filling buffer 1 then buffer 2 then 1 then 2. And you have a second thread that writes buffer 1 to disk then buffer 2 then 1. Both input and output disks are accessed sequentially (which is always the fastest) by a single thread and the two things happen in parallel so the faster process is essentially hidden.

Comment: 2) You can measure the sequential write speed of your disk easily with `dd`, reading from `/dev/zero` which can supply data at many GB/s. Just vary the `bs` (blocksize) parameter. Here's 10GB in 4kB chunks `dd if=/dev/zero of=junk bs=4k count=2500000`

Comment: @MarkSetchell So you suggest reader and writer threads with multiple buffers. How does the reader thread know when the writer has "consumed" a buffer?

Comment: @BrutusForcus There are many ways. The simplest is probably with a threading *"Event"*. See paragraph entitled **Signaling Between Threads** here https://pymotw.com/3/threading/index.html You can also use a Queue - just to pass the buffer number *NOT the data itself* because that is big and slow and already visible to both threads anyway so copying is unnecessary.

Comment: 3) On my (NVMe) disks, measured with `dd` as described above, I get 800MB/s with 4kB chunks, 1600MB/s with 16kB chunks, 2400MB/s with 64kB chunks and 2600 MB/s with 128kB chunks.

Comment: After [a somewhat thorough investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69431467/13191675), it seems (at least in my testing) chunk size has an very small effect on the transfer speed.  Any insights on my results would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments!

So I did some testing on my computer to see what would work best. So for some context I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, with an [i7-9700k](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186604/intel-core-i79700k-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html).  I am transferring a 13GB file from my [Samsung Evo 2TB](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-860-evo-2-5--sata-iii-2tb-mz-76e2t0b-am/#specs) to my [Western Digital External USB Hard Drive](https://www.cnet.com/products/wd-my-passport-fall-2016/specs/#p=wd-my-passport-fall-2016-1tb-black/).  The [external hard drive](https://www.cnet.com/products/wd-my-passport-fall-2016/specs/#p=wd-my-passport-fall-2016-1tb-black/) is configured [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/7841) in an LVM partition.  This isn't an exact replica of what will happen in production sort-of speak, since as mentioned above, the files being transferred will be several hundreds of gigabytes in size, and the computer transferring the files will have a [Ryzen 9 3900X](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-3900x), however, this gives me a good idea of what works and what does not.

So onto the results.  This is the code I used for the `move` function:

```py
import pathlib
import tqdm

def move(original: pathlib.Path, new: pathlib.Path, chunk_size: int) -> None:
    with original.open(mode='rb') as old_file, new.open(mode='wb') as new_file, \
    tqdm.tqdm(total=original.stat().st_size, unit_scale=True, unit='b') as progress:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: old_file.read(chunk_size), b''):
            new_file.write(chunk)
            progress.update(len(chunk))

    # original.unlink() Would be uncommented in production, but here
    # I did not want to have to recreate the 13 GB file after each trial.
```

I ran the following tests:

```py
>>> import timeit
>>> import shutil
>>> large_file = Path('/path/to/file')
>>> new_loc = Path('/new/file/loc')
>>> # NOTE: Using copy instead of move so I can run subsequent tests
>>> timeit.timeit('shutil.copy(large_file, new_loc)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100.30548179299967
>>> timeit.timeit('shutil.copy2(large_file, new_loc)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100.0556880589993
>>> timeit.timeit('move(large_file, new_loc, 4096)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.3G/13.3G [01:39<00:00, 133Mb/s]
103.96489155000017
>>> timeit.timeit('move(large_file, new_loc, 32_768)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.3G/13.3G [01:41<00:00, 131Mb/s]
101.63903618600034
>>> timeit.timeit('move(large_file, new_loc, 65_536)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.3G/13.3G [01:42<00:00, 130Mb/s]
102.34757778099993
>>> timeit.timeit('move(large_file, new_loc, 131_072)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.3G/13.3G [01:43<00:00, 129Mb/s]
103.19775214299989
>>> timeit.timeit('move(large_file, new_loc, 262_144)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.3G/13.3G [01:44<00:00, 127Mb/s]
104.47487919199921
>>> timeit.timeit('move(large_file, new_loc, 1_024_000)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.3G/13.3G [01:46<00:00, 124Mb/s]
106.58678834700004
>>> timeit.timeit('move(large_file, new_loc, 4096)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.3G/13.3G [01:46<00:00, 125Mb/s]
106.4800264659998
>>> timeit.timeit('move(large_file, new_loc, 10_024_000)', setup='new_loc.unlink()', number=1, globals=globals())
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.3G/13.3G [01:48<00:00, 122Mb/s]
108.68288865700015
```

So unless my testing methodology is completely incorrect it seems like chunk size has very little effect on speed.  Also it seems like `shutil.copy` is only marginally faster than just coding it yourself.  Most of the speeds are hardly changed no matter if I used a really large chunk size, or a used a small chunk size.  Also something not reflected in the results I noticed is while the program was running is during the first 10% of the progress bar the rate of transferring the data was around 420Mb/s-400Mb/s no matter which chunk size I used.  Additionally, between 10% and 20% the rate would slow decrease to 200Mb/s and then eventually stabilize around 100-130Mb/s.  I have no idea why the program would be able to read and write at 400Mb/s but then suddenly lose that ability.  Is Ubuntu rate-limiting me or something?

Also some of you may be wondering why I have the `setup='new_loc.unlink()` parameter.  For some reason when there is an already an existing file in the location of the `new_loc` the code takes like 10-20 seconds longer.

See this:

```py
>>> # NOTE: new_loc file is currently present on external USB hard drive
>>> timeit.timeit('move(large_file, new_loc, 65_536)', number=1, globals=globals())
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13.3G/13.3G [01:51<00:00, 119Mb/s]
130.79415066799993
>>> # NOTE: Took 111 seconds to actually read and write the chunks but
>>> # takes another 19 seconds to finish up for some reason
```

I have no idea why the results are the way they are but any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 100-150MB/s is about what I'd expect when writing to a little $50 USB HDD. They don't go much faster than that.

Comment: Hey @MarkSetchell, do you know why in the beginning of the transfer, speeds we recorded as high as 420Mb/s?  Why would some parts of the transfer be faster than others?

Comment: I would guess it's buffering somewhere - either in the OS or the disk. Disks often have a few MB of RAM and initial transfers will go in there and be marked as complete very fast, but as you keep writing the RAM fills up and can't be drained to physical, spinning disk fast enough to keep up.